# Android Studio file structure tabs Under Editor

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea

[image]

I can't find the file structure under the editor in Andoird Studio
Not the structure in the Tools -> Window

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can show the "Structure" section and there you can see it.

To enable it you must go to: View -> Tool Windows -> Structure

After that you will see a dock pinned like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WLjPU.png)

UPDATE:
Ohh! i'm sorry. If you want a navigation bar you can do a secondary click on margin left and later: Breadcrumbs -> Bottom [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hu3H4.png)

Comment: yes，but it don't display like my picture in my question, i don't want to see the dock, i want a navigation bar under editor